# Fitting a physical model to a specific data using nls: over-parameterization or unidentifiable parameters?

Tags: r, nls

I have somewhat a complex physical model with five unknown parameters to fit, but no success so far.

I used `nls2` first to get some estimates for the start values, but then `nls`, `nlxb`, and `nlsLM` all threw the famous "singular gradient error at initial parameter estimates" error.

For the start values for `nls2`, I extracted them from the literature, so I think that I have good starting values at least for `nls2`. The parameter estimates extracted from `nls2` make quite sense physically as well; however, don't resolve the issue with the singular gradient matrix error.

Since it's a physical model, every coefficient has a physical meaning, and I prefer not to fix any of them.

I should also mention that all five unknown parameters in the model equation are positive and the shape parameter *m* can go up to 2.

Reading through many posts and trying different solution suggestions, I have come to conclusion that I have either over-parameterization or unidentifiable parameters problem.

My question is that should I stop trying to use `nls` with this specific model (with this many unknown parameters) or is there any way out?

I am quite new to topic, so any help, mathematically or code-wise, is greatly appreciated.

Here is my MWE:

```
# Data
x <-  c(0, 1000, 2000, 2500, 2750, 3000, 3250, 3500, 3750, 4000, 5000)
y <- c(1.0, 0.99, 0.98, 0.95, 0.795, 0.59, 0.35, 0.295, 0.175, 0.14, 0.095)

# Start values for nls2
bounds <- data.frame(a = c(0.8, 1.5), b = c(1e+5, 1e+7), c = c(0.4, 1.4), n = c(0.1, 2), m = c(0.1, 2))

# Model equation function
mod <- function(x, a, b, c, n, m){
  t <- b*85^n*exp(-c/0.0309)
  (1 - exp(-(a/(t*x))^m))
}

# # Model equation
# mod <- y ~ (1 - exp(-(a/(b*85^n*exp(-c/0.0309)*x))^m))

# Model fit with nls2 
fit2 <- nls2(y ~ mod(x, a, b, c, n, m), data = data.frame(x, y), start = bounds, algorithm = "brute-force")

# Model fit with nls
fit <- nls(y ~ mod(x, a, b, c, n, m), data = data.frame(x, y), start = coef(fit2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The more I look at this the more confused I get, but I'm going to try again.

Looking again at your expression, we have the expression inside the exponential

```r
-(a/(b*85^n*exp(-c/0.0309)*x))^m
```

We can rewrite this as

```
-( [a/(b*85^n*exp(-c/0.0309))] * 1/x )^m
```

(please check my algebra!)
If this is correct, then that whole bold-faced blob doesn't affect the functional form of `x` — it all collapses to a single constant in the equation. (In other words, `{a,b,c,n}` are all *jointly unidentifiable*.) Lumping that stuff into a single parameter `phi` :

```
1 - exp(-(phi/x)^m)
```

- `phi` is a *shape parameter* (has the same units as `x`, should be roughly  the same magnitude as a typical value of `x`): let's try a starting value of 2500 (the mean value of `x`)
- `m` is a shape parameter; we can't go too badly wrong starting from `m==1`

Now `nls` works fine without any extra help:

```r
n1 <- nls(y~1 - exp(-(phi/x)^m), start=list(phi=2500,m=1), data=data.frame(x,y))
```

and gets `phi`=2935, `m`=6.49.

Plot predictions:

```r
plot(x,y, ylim=c(0,1))
xvec <- seq(0, 5000, length=101)
lines(xvec, predict(n1, newdata=data.frame(x=xvec)))
```

[image: points and predicted curve]

Another way to think about what this curve is doing: we can transform the equation to  `-log(1-y) = phi^m*(1/x)^m`: that is, `-log(1-y)` should follow a power-law curve with respect to `1/x`.

Here's what that looks like:

```r
plot(1/x, -log(1-y))
## curve() uses "x" as the current x-axis variable, i.e.
##  read "x" as "1/x" below.
with(as.list(coef(n1)), curve(phi^m*x^m, add=TRUE))
```

[image: transformed curve]

In this format, it appears to fit the central data well but fails for large values of `1/x` (the `x=0` point is missing here because it goes to infinity).

Comment: I really appreciated your effort. In fact, the model equation is a combination of two relationships. I edited the question accordingly. It's a similar case to when you put them into a single parameter of _phi_. Now _phi_ is _a/t_. But, even if we solve for _phi_, then solving for the other parameters inside it is still problematic.